Readonly con múltiples condiciones anidadas
por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar, en Odoo 16 necesito hacer un readonly con unas condiciones un poco complicada, serían estas:
readonly si (v1=A y (v3=X o v3=Y)) o (v1!=A y v2!=B y (v3=X o v3=Y o v3=Z))

Tengo este código pero me da error de:
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError, Error while validating view near

El código XML de la vista es:
<field name="campo" attrs="{  
  'readonly': [  
    '|',
    (
      ('v1', '=', 'A'), 
      '|',
      ('v3', '=', 'X'), 
      ('v3', '=', 'Y'), 
    ),
    (
      ('v1', '!=', 'A'), 
      ('v2', '!=', 'B'), 
      '|',
      '|',
      ('v3', '=', 'X'), 
      ('v3', '=', 'Y'), 
      ('v3', '=', 'Z'), 
    )
  ]  
}"/>

Ayuda por favor
